# Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device

Tags: pulseaudio, ubuntu-core, error-handling, arm

I am trying to install pocketsphinx on my ARM-based board(nanopi-m1), and use Ubuntu-Core 16.04 on it. But when I try to test pocketsphinx with this command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes
```

I get this error message:

```
Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device
```

I have instaleed `pulseaudio` and `libpulse-dev` before installing pocketsphinx, but I get the error message!